# CSS, HTML @-webkit-keyframes without Style Script

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to not use a style script to include @-webkit-keyframes inside an element, like:

```
<div style="@-webkit-keyframes {...}">
  ...
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="anim">
  ...
</div>

<style>
  @-webkit-keyframes anim {
    ...
  }

  ...
</style>
```

???

Comment: Have you tried putting the `style` tags in the `head` of the page.?

Comment: That's not what I want to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to include it in an external stylesheet or a style tag? Are you unable to add a stylesheet or style tags?

Comment: I am including it in a post on a website were you can ONLY use css in elements and where you CAN'T use <style> property.

Answer (score -1):

uses many brackets `{}` and styles in html does not work with clamps `{}`.

only `style="color:red;width:20em;position:absolute"`

```
<p class="youclass">hola</p>
```

css

```
.youclass{    
-webkit-animation: timereproduce-reproducing-after 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes timereproduce-reproducing-after {
    0% { color: red;}
    100% {color: yellow;}
}
```

Comment: Without using a css class! All wrapped inside style="..."!